# Shopify create custom product (Giveaway Booking) see the below description

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I need this type of custom section in Shopify
Here are the details of the custom section

In Giveaway Booking, customers can customize a bundle for events like weddings, birthdays, bridal showers, etc.

You first select a category: Perfume, All Over Cologne, or Swashes
Respectively, you can select a product or multiple products within that category and select a bulk quantity that you like. You may also enter specific quantities for each product. The price would be changed accordingly. You also see a preview of the product you have selected on the side.

Furthermore, you have the option to select a sticker type. It may be default or custom. In custom sticker type, a customer can enter the text that they would like to print on the selected product. You can also change the font of the sticker below the text field for entering the sticker text.

Next up are the sleeves. You have various default options to select from for the gift wrap/ribbon and you may also enter a custom text that you want printing there or upload your own custom design.

You then finally enter your personal and delivery information before proceeding to the checkout page.

**Note:** Giveaway booking products are different you can see the screenshot of to option Original & Custom

I have added the screenshot of the design.
Step 1. https://prnt.sc/0jC4ehMremve
Step 2. https://prnt.sc/luzfNE4I9cA8
Step 3. https://prnt.sc/VKod8NaWgabn
Step 4. https://prnt.sc/HkahPKPvOmZZ
Step 5. https://prnt.sc/WW82rwTy2_MH
Step 6. https://prnt.sc/NGcKNZef-WHW
Step 7. https://prnt.sc/xdlApmZ3Anwm

Comment: What Shopify plan?

Comment: @TwistedOwl current Development plan

Comment: Depending on plan you will have different solutions unless you plan to stay on development plan forever ;).

Comment: What is the solution? @TwistedOwl

Comment: Is it shopify plus?

Comment: No, It's not Shopify plus

Comment: Without the Shopify Plus plan the easiest solution would be to try bundle builder apps unless you can afford custom app development. In that case you need to build a custom app that will process a request coming from the frontend to quickly create a given product and on response add it to the cart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251359/discussion-between-savan-dholu-and-twistedowl).